# solutions to the equation $(2m^2-1)^2=2n^2-1$, where $m$, $n$ are positive integers

Tags: diophantine-equations

I'm studying the equation $(2m^2-1)^2=2n^2-1$ ($\ast$), where $m$, $n$ are positive integers. It is known that $m$ can only be 1 or 2 by using Wolfram Alpha. Now I want to prove that result.

That is my attempt: If a prime $p$ | gcd($m$, $n$), ($\ast$) is equivalent to $(2m^2-1)(m^2-1)=(n-m)(n+m)$, $p$ divides RHS but not LHS, which is impossible. So gcd($m$, $n$)=1. Module 8 to ($\ast$) and we find $n$ must be odd. This is as far as I got. Can someone help me?

Comment: How do you get
$$(2m^2-1)(m^2-1)=(n-m)(n+m)$$

Comment: FYI, using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24(2m%5E2-1)%5E2%3D2n%5E2-1%24&p=1), there's the duplicate [How to solve $(2x^2-1)^2=2y^2 - 1$ in positive integers?](/q/1166449). It has $2$ upvoted answers, but neither fully solve your question, so I'm not voting to close as a duplicate. Note the results also include the AoPS threads [Number Theory: Diophantine equation](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1908286p13064160) and [The Integer Chase](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4h1342279p7293162) (post #$18$ is particularly pertinent).

Comment: We can find the integral solutions of $n^2 = 2m^4-2m^2+1$  using online Magma calculator as follows.
IntegralQuarticPoints$([2,0,-2,0,1]).$
It says that all integral points are [ [ 0, 1 ], [ 1, 1 ], [ -1, 1 ], [ 2, 5 ], [ -2, 5 ]].
Hence all positive integral points are $(m,n)=(1,1),(2,5)$.

Comment: @John Omielan It is really a good website, thanks.

Comment: One has also $n^2 = (m^2)^2+(m^2-1)^2$ which is a primitive Pythagorean triple, I think this lead to elementary but lengthy solution by converting to $x^4\pm y^4=z^2$, though I can't recall details.

Comment: it follows, not immediately, from the fact that the Pell number sequence  $0, 1, 2, 5, 12, 29, 70, 169, 408,$   contains the squares $0,1, 169$   but no others. Proof by Ljunggren (1942).  Discussion in English in J. H. E. Cohn (1996)  Perfect Pell Powers.

Answer (score 2):

COMMENT (*just for fun*).- Your equation has solution modulo all integer, because if $f(m,n)=2m^4-2m^2-n^2+1$ then  $f(2,5)=f(1,1)=0$, so all "local" method is not useful (unless restrictions but for the first primes till $19$ there are other solutions and for greater primes brute force becomes hard). Because of squares we can just to try with positive integers. The problem is difficult.

We have $(2m^2-1)^2=2n^2-1\iff 2m^4-2m^2-n^2+1=0$ solving the quadratic in $m^2$ we get
$$m^2=\frac{1+\sqrt{2n^2-1}}{2}\hspace1cm(1)$$ which imposes for some integer $x$, $$2n^2-1=x^2\hspace1cm(2)$$ Equation $(2)$ has infinitely many solutions given by
$$x=-\frac12[(1+\sqrt2)(3-2\sqrt2)^k+(1-\sqrt2)(3+2\sqrt2)^k]; \space k\ge0$$ for example, for $k=1,2,3,4,5$, we have respectively
$x=1,7,41,239,1393$ which in equation $(1)$ gives $m^2=1,4,21,120,697$ respectively
so only the two first values given  a square. We get the two solutions $(m,n)=(1,1),(2,5)$ given by the O.P.

Consequently a way of proving these are the only solutions, can be to prove that
$$4m^2-2=-[(-7+5\sqrt2)(3-2\sqrt2)^{k-2}-(7+5\sqrt2)(3+2\sqrt2)^{k-2}]\hspace1cm(3)$$ has no solution for all integer $k\gt2\iff h=k-2\gt0$.

Maybe someone can finish using equation $(3)$.

Answer (score 0):

There is already an elementary proof in $\textit{Number Theory: Conceptions and Problems}$ written by Titu Andreescu et al. , which is example 3.56.

Comment: apparently one with Mushkarov, https://www.awesomemath.org/product/number-theory-concepts-and-problems/?gad_source=1&gclid=CjwKCAjwh4-wBhB3EiwAeJsppJZ-zjyv3CzhQibe6Fr09433Tz5bnCUbAmzDVKjmHatslbq01XGXlxoCbBMQAvD_BwE